# Microsoft Excel 2019 not responding

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-2019

I am using MS Office 2019. I have an excel file of 3,776 KB. It takes so much time to open and once it is open it hangs a lot. If I try to select the cell to edit it says "not responding". I have another file of 1126 KB and it is working fine.

I have tried quick repair but it doesn't help. File contains only text which is written in urdu font.

Comment: Is it  an `.xlsx` or `.xlsm` macro file? Also, you sure it's just text and not any volatile functions/formulas and/or conditional formatting?

Comment: @JvdV yes sure about it. It's .xsls file.

Answer (score 0):

Is the file larger than you think? Once the file has opened use the keys "Control + end" to jump to the bottom right of the used area of the spreadsheet. You may find this is larger than the area that you have actually got data in. If data is accidentally entered into a cell at the bottom of the spreadsheet Excel will create every cell down to that spot, and they hang around even if the data is subsequentially deleted. If that is your problem you will need to delete the faulty rows and then resave and reload the spreadsheet to get rid of them. This should reduce the size and thus improve the responses of the workbook.

Comment: I have another file of 1126 KB and it is working fine. After pressing "Control + end" it gets not responding.